# why is this oscilloscope so cheap with a 20Gsa/s sampling resolution?

Tags: oscilloscope, sampling

I've looked around this site but I haven't been able to figure out why this oscilloscope seems to have such a high sampling rate "Repetitive mode: 20GSa/S"  and be relatively cheap:
http://shop1.usbdso.com/MSO-9201-with-Logic-Analyzer-MSO-9201wla.htm

Can someone explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is for a repetitive signal like a standing sine wave.

When I buy a scope I always look for is the real-time sample rate which indicates the maximum rate an incoming signal can be acquired in a single-shot acquisition. On the other hand, repetitive sample is a method of reconstructing a signal based on a series of triggered waveforms that are each acquired in single-shot mode. The advantage of repetitive mode is that it offers a higher effective sample rate. The downside, however, is that it takes more time and is applicable only for repetitive signals. This scope has a real time rate of only 200MSa/s - far from the 20GSa/s.

In general I hate using PC based oscilloscopes and would tell you to go for something like [this](http://www.rigolna.com/products/digital-oscilloscopes/ds1000Z/ds1104z-s/) instead if you're in the market for a scope to use. Unless you are really strapped for money and need the 200MHz bandwidth or really need the deep sample rate.

Comment: Also called equivalent-time sampling.

Comment: Hi Gonzik, what does the equivalent sample rate mean in the following link? http://www.rigolna.com/products/digital-oscilloscopes/ds1000e/

Comment: Equivalent-time and repetitive sample are the same thing as pointed out by user36129 above.

Comment: Short version: Lies from the marketing department.

Comment: Ok now, I get user36129. Thanks everyone for your help!